# Where is the text of Friday night Kiddush from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, kiddush, text, leil-shabbat

There is a fairly uniform text for Kiddush Friday night.  There are some differences between the Ashkenazi and Sfardi versions, but they are mostly very similar.

What is the source for the text?  As far as I know, it isn't in the Talmud anywhere.  The Tur comments on certain phrases, but he doesn't include the text of the bracha; neither do the Beit Yosef or the Bach.

So where can I find the earliest version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The berachah is in [Siddur R. Amram Gaon](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14439&pgnum=35), and almost identically in [Siddur R. Saadyah Gaon](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=174). Both of them also say that it should be prefaced with Vayechulu and the berachah on the wine.

Comment: Interesting that neither of those are what Ashkenazim say today.  Though the footnote suggests looking at Bavli Ketuvot Daf Zayin for Rashi's version.

Comment: Ketubot: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%96_%D7%91 in case anyone is following along.  Oddly enough, the text in the Geonim is not identical to either the Sfardi or Ashkenazi minhag.

Comment: @avi I don't know how the Ashkenazi version varies (is it the omission of ...כי בנו as in some Chasidish versions?), but the only difference between the standard Chasidish version and R' Amram Gaon is the addition of וברצון between באהבה and הנחילנו.

Comment: @yoel three differences. Add "uvratzon" and  add "Ki hoo yom" (before Tehila)  and Replae "Mikreh" with "L'Mikrai"

Comment: @avi oops, forgot about ki hu yom - do most say that?  I've never heard it, I don't think, only seen it.  Isn't it "mikrai" in R'Amram Gaon's?  So it's just the addition of "L'".  Anybody got a link to the Sefardi kiddush?  Now I'm curious..

Comment: @yoel Standard Ashkenaz kiddush includes Ki Hu Yom. It was removed in some circles at some point historically by certain Kabbalists for Kabbalistic reasons.